# Are Soul Gem fragments worth keeping?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been occasionally finding soul gem fragments in certain dungeons in Skyrim. Since they weigh so little, I've been picking them up just in case. Well, I've accumulated about 20 of them now so I'm wondering if they serve any purpose. Can I do anything with soul gem fragments?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Within the strategy guide for Skyrim the soul gem fragments are listed under "Clutter" so they are not important or useful items. They may be requested as part of a radiant quest though.